# Does asp.net MVC depends on Normal asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

this is my first question Here ,

I am a beginner in asp.net , and i want to make a CMS project using it
After Some readings I found that the MVC structure is very suitable for Me

Just want to know :
 **how much the asp.net MVC depend on the normal asp.net??**

as a beginner i don't know the level of knowledge for Normal asp.net to start working using asp.net MVC

**Please tell me where to start in the normal asp.net(3.5) and when to switch to learn the asp.net MVC ??**

**Detailed information is very welcome**

Thanks For your Time

Answer (score 3):

It is built on normal ASP.NET minus postbacks, viewstate, and event wiring. The underlying System.Web stuff is the same, but with some new wrappers to access it, and of course a bunch of new featuers that make up the MVC portion. Just get a book on ASP.NET MVC, and don't worry about classic ASP.NET.

Comment: interesting how you refered to it as Classic ASP.Net ;)

Comment: Actually ASP.NET MVC looks more like 'Classic ASP' than it does 'Classic ASP.Net'. Strange how the wheel turns.

Answer (score 2):

'normal' (also known as WebForms) asp.net and 'mvc' asp.net are somewhat different from each other in how things are put together and how things work with each other. There is no need to learn one before learning the other.

If you read through [this article](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/09/difference-between-aspnet-webforms-and.html)  you can see at a glance what the differences are between 'normal' or WebForms and 'mvc'.

Here is a pretty good [tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx) for learning about MVC from Scott Guthrie if this is the way that you're leaning.

Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "ASP.NET". ASP.NET MVC does depend on standard ASP.NET request processing pipeline (`IHttpModule`s, `IHttpHandler`s and all other internal workings), but it does not depend on WebForms infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently jumped on the ASP.NET MVC bandwagon and I found the [introduction tutorials](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/?lang=cs) on the official http://asp.net/mvc site very useful.

ASP.NET WebForms tried to mimic WinForms desktop apps in that you have controls and event-driven interaction, which is not particularly well suited to the stateless HTTP

ASP.NET MVC gives you full control over the HTML that is generated and sent back to the browser, but more importantly, it makes it easier to write testable code.

Also, ASP.NET MVC does not depend on ASP.NET WebForms, they are built on the same foundation. In fact, in principle, you can mix and use both in the same app if you really wanted to :)

Answer (score 0):

When MVC was released, what used to be simply ASP.NET was renamed ASP.NET Webforms and MVC because ASP.NET MVC.  Not sure if that answers your question but it does clear up some terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Why not start with Asp.Net MVC ?

Asp.Net is split now into 2 parts. Webforms and MVC.

I'd advise looking at the following -

http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/mischa/archive/2008/02/04/asp-net-mvc-vs-asp-net-webforms-vs-ruby-on-rails.aspx
http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/